# Avoid app logic that relies on enumerating keys on a component instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

in my complex Vue project I am getting this console warning:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid app logic that relies on enumerating keys on a component instance.  The keys will be empty in production mode to avoid performance overhead.

Unfortunately I can not find the reason for this warning just by the above message.

How can I track down the reason for this warning?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but looking at the source it seems that they have this [ownKeys trap](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/de954f45600cd31e189a02f0ccd660f26f2c8dcc/packages/runtime-core/src/componentPublicInstance.ts#L441-L446) which can intercept [these operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/ownKeys#interceptions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if your watching an entire route object anywhere in your code. Doing so throws that error (in my case).

Refer this vue documentation on watching routes
[Accessing router and current route inside setup](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#accessing-the-router-and-current-route-inside-setup)

The route object is a reactive object, so any of its properties can be watched and you should avoid watching the whole route object. In most scenarios, you should directly watch the param you are expecting to change.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the router ...Why everone keep saying that ?! In my code It's coming each time I send a request

Comment: In my case it was exactly this problem: I was watching the route-object.

Comment: In my case it happens when I watch `route.matched` (not entire the route object). How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

So I was also having this issue, but not for the reasons the accepted answer provided.  It was occurring due to my Vuex store.  After a lot of digging I discovered the cause was the presence of the "CreateLogger" plugin.

So if you're having this issue and it's not due to you watching an entire route, check if you're using the CreateLogger plugin in Vuex.  That might be the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

This happens for me when I pass `this` to a data object

```
data() {
    return {
       updateController: new UpdateController({
           reportTo: this
       })
    }   
}
```

This used to work fine with Vue 2 but causes this error in Vue 3.
Making this modification solved the problem for me.

```
data() {
    return {
       updateController: new UpdateController({
           reportTo: () => this
       })
    }   
}
```

I know this might be anti-pattern but I needed to inject partial reactivity to a non-reactive part of a JS library and this was the most not complicated way of achieving this that I can think of.

Comment: Adding a plus 1 for this as it solved my problem. I also stored an instance of `this` (my component) in the Vuex store and called one of its methods from there.

Answer (score 2):

Was able to fix this with the suggestion done by Glass Cannon.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/70205284/11787139)

To clarify and maybe help someone else: I was trying to send an Axios request to the server of which the data I sent through was composed of a **direct component reference** emitted by the component function.

**Component**

```
saveItem(){
    this.saved = true;
    setTimeout( this.resetState, 2500);
    this.$emit('saveitem', this)
},
```

**Parent**

```
saveitem(e){
    const data = {item : e}
    axios.post(target, data, {headers . . .).then((response) => {}
})
```

The error disappeared when I instead fetched the **index of the list item** by doing so:

```
    saveitem(e){
        let item;
    
        this.items.forEach( function(item, index, array)  {
            if(item.id == e.id) pointer = item
        })
        data.item = pointer
        
        axios.post(target, data, {headers . . .).then((response) => {}
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when destructuring a ref without `.value`.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me only in Firefox, and when I removed the Vue Dev Tools extension it stopped. After re-installing Vue dev tools it hasn't come back. Make sure you have the latest version of the Vue Dev Tools for your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this problem can have a multitude of origins. In my case (after spending way to many hours debugging my code), upgrading from Vue 3.3.something to Vue 3.4.15 simply made the problem dissapear...

Comment: thanks, that worked for me too, but that's not even an reliable reason what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the plethora of ways it seems like this warning can show up. I was not watching the entire route object at all.

I got this in a very specific case. I had a `beforeEach` navigation guard that tries to preserve url search params, like this:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  const newTo = { ...to, query: { ...from.query, ...to.query } };
  // naive deep equality check to prevent infinite redirects (more bad vue-router design imo)
  if (JSON.stringify(newTo) !== JSON.stringify(to)) return newTo;
});
```

Then I would get the warning when clicking on `#` links, for some reason...

If you look at the full `to` object in a navigation guard, it looks like this:

```js
({
  fullPath: "/page-c?count=13#123",
  path: "/page-c",
  query: {
    count: "13",
  },
  hash: "#123",
  params: {},
  matched: [
    {
      path: "/page-c",
      meta: {},
      props: {
        default: false,
      },
      children: [],
      instances: {
        default: {},
      },
      leaveGuards: {},
      updateGuards: {},
      enterCallbacks: {},
      components: {
        default: {
          __hmrId: "a96e6b7d",
          __file: "/Users/vincerubinetti/Desktop/vue-use-url/src/PageC.vue",
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  meta: {},
  name: undefined,
  href: "/page-c?count=13#123",
  redirectedFrom: undefined,
})
```

I *think* `vue-router` is complaining that I'm spreading the *entire* `to` object in my return redirect, including stuff like `components`, `instances` (?), etc. that is either considered "under-the-hood" or otherwise not supposed to be returned for some reason. If that's the case, this is bad design imo, you should be able to spread everything for safety and convenience.

Anyway, I was able to make the warning go away by just returning a few props I needed to preserve:

```js
router.beforeEach(({ path, query, hash }, from) => {
  const oldTo = { path, query, hash };
  const newTo = { ...oldTo };
  newTo.query = { ...from.query, ...newTo.query };
  newTo.hash = newTo.hash || from.hash || "";
  // naive deep equality check to prevent infinite redirects (more bad vue-router design imo)
  if (JSON.stringify(newTo) !== JSON.stringify(oldTo)) return newTo;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me:

unhandled exception in `onMounted`